# Validating a Date mm/dd/yyyy form in python

Tags: python-3.5

I have two question 1_ I can't use this form 05/04/2011 keep giving me an error 
2_ I can't block the user from using a negative numbers. 
here is the code:

```
def main():
    # ask the user for a date as a string in the form mm/dd/yyyy
    date = input("Please enter a date in form mm/dd/yyyy: ")
    months, days, years = date.split("/")

    # ask about the month 
    m = range(1,13)
    months = m[eval(months)-1]
    # april have only 30 days
    if months in range(4,5):
        D = range(1,31)
        Days = D[eval(days)-1]
    # june have only 30 days
    elif months in range(6,7):
        D = range(1,31)
        Days = D[eval(days)-1]
    # september have only 30 days
    elif months in range(9,10):
        D = range(1,31)
        Days = D[eval(days)-1]
    # november have only 30 days 
    elif months in range(11,12):
        D = range(1,31)
        Days = D[eval(days)-1]
    # ask about days 
    d = range(1,32)
    days = d[eval(days)-1]
    # ask about the years
    y = range(1,2017)
    years = y[eval(years)-1]
    if months <= 0:
        print("you can't use a nagatve number")
    if days <= 0:
        print("you can't use negaive numbers")
    if years <= 0:
        print("you can't use negaiive numbers")
    print(months,"/",days,"/",years,"is a valid date")
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the Python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) library, specifically to `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`

Instead of writing your own buggy date-parser, you can then use:

```
datestring = input("Please enter a date in form mm/dd/yyyy: ")
try:
    date = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%m/%d/%Y')
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid date entered!")
```

Your code contains some really bad practices, for example you should never use `eval` for simply evaluating a string to an integer, while you are using it all over the place. Rather than:

```
m = range(1,13)
months = m[eval(months)-1]
```

You could have simply written:

```
months = int(months)
```

And code such as `months in range(4,5)` can be rewritten as `months == 4`, but you could also have used `if months in [4, 6, 9, 1]:`. But you totally forgot about February, which also depends on whether or not the current year is a leap year.